# knockoutjs save multiple viewmodels from one function?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have spent the last few days researching the following KnockoutJS issue.

I have a page with 3 viewmodels on. I am using div's with id's to specify the bindings i.e:

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(datasource), $("#sectionQualifications")[0]);
```

I am also using RequireJS which has really helped with making my app modular and works well with KnockoutJS of course.

My question relates to having (as mentioned) 3 viewmodels on my page.. none overlap, but each viewmodel has a SAVE function.  So a quick look at one of the viewmodel snippets:

```
function viewModel(data) {
        self = this;

        self.quals = ko.observableArray(data),

        self.addQual = function () {
            self.quals.push(new qualification());
        },

        self.remove = function (item) {

            //  Remove from the database IF we have an actual record in our viewmodel
            if (item.Id !== 0) {
                dataservice_qualifications.deleteEntity(item.Id, ko.toJSON(item),
                    {
                        success: function (ret) {
                            common.notifyOK('Qualification removed');
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            common.notifyError('Cannot remove that qualification');
                            console.log('Qualification Remove Error', err);
                            console.log('Remove error object', this.Id);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

            //  Remove from the actual view model
            self.quals.remove(item);
        }

        //  Save and move on.. we need to iterate through the qualifications, update any existing rows (ID NOT 0) or
        //  add new entries (ID IS 0)
        self.save = function () {

            var saveData = ko.toJS(this.quals);
            for (var i in saveData) {

                //  New qualification entry
                if (saveData[i].Id === 0) { // New qualification entry
                    dataservice_qualifications.postEntity(ko.toJSON(saveData[i]),
                        {
                            success: function (ret) {
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                common.notifyError('Cannot add qualification ' + saveData[i].qualificationName);
                                console.log('Qualification add error', error);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                } // eof NEW qualification

                if (saveData[i].Id > 0) {
                    dataservice_qualifications.putEntity(saveData[i].Id, ko.toJSON(saveData[i]),
                        {
                            success: function (ret) {
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                common.notifyError('Cannot update qualification ' + saveData[i].qualificationName);
                                console.log('UPDATED: ERROR:', error);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                } // eof UPDATED qualification

            } // eof saveData loop

            common.notifyOK('Qualifications updated');

        } // eof savenext function

        return;
    };
```

So from that above sample, I would have 2 other viewmodels that are similar, which have the SAVE function as above.  So of course I want to use say jQuery to click a button and save all 3 viewmodels (i.e. via that SAVE function on each).

Because I am using RequireJS, I have tried exposing a "public" function that in turn tries to internally call the viewModel.save() function as follows in this snippet:

```
function saveModel() {
    viewModel.save();

}

//  PUBLIC INTERFACE
return {
    saveModel: saveModel,
    loadViewModel: koMapData
}
```

So the theory being I can call the "saveModel" function from wherever which should trigger the save of the viewmodels?

Any help really appreciated.  By the way I have gone down the path of trying to create the viewmodel like:

```
var viewModel = {

    save: function() {
        blah blah...
    }
}
```

however no real luck in that either?  I am sure I am missing something simple, because I would think you could/should be able to trigger a function from a viewmodel externally somehow?

**EDIT**
Just for reference, the models DO NOT overlap..

Thanks in advance,
David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thanks @XGreen for your suggestion, and I can see that working well, however I am using requirejs, and so my app structure isn't quite a match.

However, I have been successful in the following solution:

First, I created the viewmodel in a slightly different way..

```
var viewModel = {
  quals: ko.observableArray([]),

  addQual: function () {
    viewModel.quals.push(new qualification());
  },

  remove: function (item) {
    // Do the remove bit..
  },

  save: function () {
    var saveData = ko.toJS(viewModel.quals);
    // Do the save stuff..
  } // eof savenext function

}; // eof viewModel def
```

So the viewmodel is defined, and then I had a helper function to access just the SAVE function of the viewmodel:

```
//  Private:    Allows external access to save the viewmodel
var viewModelFunctions = {
    saveModel: function () {
        viewModel.save();
    }
}
```

.. and then finally, because I am using the revealing module pattern within the requirejs structure, I created a public interface function as follows:

```
function koMapData(incomingData) {
    datasource = (incomingData === null) ? [new qualification()] : incomingData;
    viewModel.quals = ko.observableArray(ko.toJS(datasource));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#sectionQualifications")[0]);
}

//  PUBLIC INTERFACE
return {
    viewModelFunctions: viewModelFunctions,
    loadViewModel: koMapData
}
```

**So** you can see the last part with the viewModelFunctions, which means in another module (or wherever) I can reference/trigger the SAVE function remotely by:

```
mymodule.viewModelFunctions.saveModel()
```

Which also means (in my case because I have 3 viewmodels I need to trigger save for from one event) I can have the flexibility of saving when/how I want to.  Obviously it would be good to return any errors too etc up to the calling module, but that is in principle how it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge view models in an object like this:

```
var mainVModel = {
    vModel1: { // has save method},
    vModel2: { // has save method},
    saveAll : function(){
        mainVModel.vModel1.save();
        mainVModel.vModel2.save();
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new mainVModel());
```